# how to target all tags except one with jquery and css :not() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to catch all click events except if they are done on a a-tag.

i build this fiddle to show my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/vwyFg/7/

why does this not work?

```
$('.three').on('click',':not(a)',function(e){
    $('body').append('<b>i did not click on a a-tag!</b><br>');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="wrap three">
    <div class="wrap two">
        <div class="wrap one">
            <a href="javascript:$('body').append('i DID click on a a-tag!!<br>');;return false;">klick me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: $('.three').on('click',':not(a)'  Basically you are skipping click event on 'A' tag but dont stop propagation to the parent element which then will trigger the click event

Comment: `e.preventDefault` did indeed prevent the href from being executed.
But i still dont get it: why cant i filter the incoming events with `:not(...)` ?
without the :not it works as i would expect:
http://jsfiddle.net/vwyFg/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check where the click event orginated:

```
$('div.three').on('click',function(e){    
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') return;
    $('body').append('<b>i did not click on a a-tag!</b><br>');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Comment: I think the question becomes: Why is this necessary? Changing `:not(a)` to `a` works just fine (albeit opposite). This appears to be some kind of bug in jQuery.

Comment: $('.three').on('click','*',function(e){  is better, that way you keep delegation and you are not limited to just DIV element

Comment: @Eric   This is the normal behaviour, if clicked element is a 'A' element, do nothing. Parent of this 'A' element then will intercept the click event.

Comment: @roasted Doesn't the `href` tag on the `a` have an implicit click handler? Seems to me having `:not(a)`, and clicking on an `a`, should have the same effect as no click handler at all.

Comment: @Eric This is not really a implicit click event, it is a native behaviour from href attribute which is always triggered after all mouse events. In this case, i suspect the e.stopPropagation() generated from parent div to disabled the href behaviour, although im not completly confident with this affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this, note the placement of the :not -

```
$('.three:not(a)').on('click',function(e){
    $('body').append('<b>i did not click on a a-tag!</b><br>');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: the idea was to improve a scripts performance by reducing the number of event listeners.
i thing with your example i would use many listeners ..

Comment: It is using one listener - the click handler. You didn't talk about that in your original post, you asked why what you were doing wasn't working.

Comment: This snippet change nothing to the problem

Comment: Actually it did. If you click on .three in the original nothing happens at all. Moving the :not selector makes the .three available for click. It is subtle, but you have to click on the fuchsia colored div to see the difference @roasted.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code:

```
$(".three a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

see here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h89dc/1/)